# Is it possible to bind necessarily different terms in Ltac-match?

Tags: pattern-matching, coq, ltac

When pattern matching (with `match goal with`) in a user-defined tactic, we can use `?x` to bind a Gallina term, so that later we can refer to it. We can use several such identifiers in one clause (`... ?x ... ?y ...`) or we can even use the same identifier (`... ?x ... ?x ...`) to indicate that in order for the clause to match, the same Gallina term must appear in those two positions.  In a way, this constraints the possible matches with a "sameness" requirement. That's handy, but it would be handier (sic) to also be able to pose a "different" requirement. Is there a way to write a match-clause of the form `... ?x ... ?y ...` where we require that the terms bound by `?x` and `?y` are distinguishable?

By distinguishable I don't necessarily mean not-equal, but just different (their names [or representations] don't coincide). For example, say I have two terms `a,b:C`. The two terms might be equal in the sense that we can prove the proposition `a = b`, but that's irrelevant for my purposes. What makes `a` and `b` distinguishable from each other is that their names are different.

**So, can I pattern-match by posing a requirement that two meta-variables `?x` and `?y` must bind different terms?**

To put this in some context, say we have defined pairs, projections and let `R` be some (appropriately typed) binary relation. Suppose I somehow end up with the following two in my assumptions.

```
H  : R (proj1 (pair a b)) c
H' : R (proj1 (pair a b)) a
```

I would like to be able to write a match-clause in my tactic that will only match `H` and not `H'`. Is there a trick for that?

If there is no way to only match `H`, then perhaps I could match both, where I bind `a` to `?x` and `c` (or again `a`) to `?y`. But then, on the right-hand-side of the match-clause I would like to perform some "*are-they-different?*" check between `x` and `y` and do `idtac` in case the two bind literally the same terms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are [several tactics to check whether two terms are equal](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#checking-properties-of-terms).

I think you can combine it with [`tryif`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/ltac.html#coq:tacn.tryif) or [`assert_fails`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/ltac.html#coq:tacn.assert-fails) to do what you want.

```
match goal with
  | [H : ... |- _] => tryif (constr_eq x y) then fail else some_tactic
end.
```